# Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I am getting this error while using angular 11.0 with native script and android (on importing webcam module to app.module from npm):

```
Error: ./node_modules/ngx-webcam/fesm2015/ngx-webcam.mjs 482:20-42
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above error by
migrating  my angular application cli version from 11.0 to 12.2.16 (or latest stable version ).
After that, camera feature was working fine